# return ping result every ping, and not only in the end

Tags: java, ping

im doing a little desktop app for a friend to do pings, it "works", im planning to use the  ping -t (for infinite ping), but in the way i did, it will never show the results, since it only return when finish, what i have to change/add to add everyping result in the "jtextField"

look what i have:

method to do the ping and return the result (resposta).

```
    public String pingar(String ip){  
        String resposta="";  
        String comando="ping -t "+ip;  
        try {  
            Scanner S = new Scanner( Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando).getInputStream());    
            while(S.hasNextLine()) {    
               resposta+=S.nextLine()+"\n"; 
            }  
        } catch (IOException ex) {  
            ex.printStackTrace();  
        }  
        return resposta;  
    }
```

method to start the method above and use the method adicionaresultado to append the result(resposta)
        public void ativaoping() {
            adicionaresultado((pingar(tfIp.getText())));
            }

the method to change/append the text and set the position of the scroll to the end

```
    public void adicionaresultado(String resposta) { 
        taResultados.append(resposta);
taResultados.setCaretPosition(taResultados.getDocument().getLength());  
        //tfResultado.setText(tfResultado.getText() + "\n" + resposta);
    }
}
```

but my problem is that it only return and add the text when it finish the ping, so i will never be abble to use the ping -t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add the text to the JTextArea on the event queue. I've put a very rudimentary example in the code example that follows. This appends a new line to the JTextArea for the response from the ping command. It is not pretty, but it does what you need.
Also, you want to put the endless pinging into a separate runnable, so you can kill it later, and run it inside an executor, so you can have greater control over how you kill it.

```
package test;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Pinger {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Pinger pinger = new Pinger();
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                frame.setSize(300, 400);
                frame.add(panel);
                JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
                panel.add(textArea);
                frame.setVisible(true);
                pinger.executor.execute(pinger.createRunnable("google.com",
                        textArea));
            }
        });

    }

    private Runnable createRunnable(final String ip, final JTextArea area) {
        return new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                String resposta = "";
                String comando = "ping -t " + ip;

                try {
                    Scanner S = new Scanner(Runtime.getRuntime().exec(comando)
                            .getInputStream());
                    while (S.hasNextLine()) {
                        final String newText = S.nextLine();
                        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                area.setText(area.getText()
                                        + System.getProperty("line.separator")
                                        + newText);
                            }
                        });

                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };
    }

    Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

}
```

Comment: nice, but how would i kill it? i solved the issue of jtextarea with another thing, but i will try your, but if i want to STOP te ping/close the window using your code, what will be the command

Comment: Instead of declaring the pinger.executor as an Executor, declare it as an ExecutorService, and then you get access to the #shutdown() and #awaitTermination methods. These permit you to kill the executor and all of its managed runnables.

Comment: huum, @codethulhu  i understand, im using this: 
        pinger.executor.shutdown(); and

   pinger.executor.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
   
  System.out.println(pinger.executor.isShutdown());
  .... but it still display in TextArea the result of ping and the PING, conhost.exe still in process list ;( i have to kill it manually?

Comment: This question has moved beyond your original question. Please mark some answer as correct and post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Call `adicionaResultado` every time there is a new line in the stream.

```
while(S.hasNextLine()) {    
    adicionaResultado(S.nextLine()+"\n");
}
```

Comment: dont work, still adding to the jtextArea only in the end of the ping... if i use system.out, it works, but append not..

Answer (score 0):

A method can return only once , So this trick will do

```
           while(S.hasNextLine()) {    
               System.out.print(S.nextLine()+"\n"); 
            }
```

Comment: dont work, still adding to the jtextArea only in the end of the ping... if i use system.out, it works, but append not..

Answer (score 0):

Replace this: "ping -t " + ip; 
for 
this:  String comando = "ping -n 10 " + ip;